# Add horizontal line to AmCharts4 Dumbbell plot

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

I would like to add an horizontal line to an [AmCharts4 Dumbbell plot](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/dumbbell-plot/). Since the x-axis is categorical, is it possible? The line must have different settings than the lines of the grid (e.g. larger, dashed, colored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/axis-ranges/#Single_lines).

```
var range = valueAxis.axisRanges.create();
range.value = 1000;
range.grid.stroke = am4core.color("#396478");
range.grid.strokeWidth = 2;
range.grid.strokeOpacity = 1;
range.grid.strokeDasharray = "6,3";
```

This works for other kinds of charts, of course.